# Closure of $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ in vertical interval topology

Tags: general-topology

The vertical interval topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by topology that is generated by $\{a\}\times I$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $I$ is open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to find the closure of $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. So my idea is $(0,1)\times [0,1]$ is the closure since the set is closed in the topology and contains $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. The idea is since the topology is actually the product between discrete and Euclidean topology, and we know the closures of $(0,1)$ in each topology. But I have difficulty to show that this is the smallest closed set that contains $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your proposed closure, say $\overline{X} = (0, 1) \times [0, 1]$, comprises the original set, say $X = (0, 1) \times (0, 1)\;\;$, together with a set of extra points comprising all points of the form $(x, 0)$ and $(x, 1)$ with $x \in (0, 1)$. Each of those extra points is a limit point of the original set $X$ (do you see why?) and so must be included in the closure. As $\overline{X}$ is indeed closed as you have proved, you are there.

More detail after comments: if $F$ is a closed set containing $X$, assume for a contradiction that $(x, 0) \not\in F$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$, then $(x, 0)$ is in the complement of $F$, which is an open set. So there is an open set containing $(x, 0)$ which does not meet $X$, but this cannot be the case. Likewise if $(x, 0) \not\in F$.

Comment: I haven't learned the concept of limit point yet, we just defined only the definition of closure. Does there exist a way to avoid limit point?

Comment: Every extra point in $\overline{X}$ has a neighbourhood that meets $X$. Does that work with the concepts you have learnt so far?

Comment: Not yet actually, that's why I have difficulty. So what I learnt is the closure is intersection of closed sets containing the set. I wanted to show if $F$ is arbitrary vlosed set containing $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, then it contains also $(0,1)\times[0,1]$. But I am not sure how to do this

Comment: @LaurencePW Try showing that an open set that is disjoint from $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ also must be disjoint from $(0, 1) \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: @RobertShore ok thank you.

Comment: @LaurencePW More simply, show that the complement of $(0, 1) \times [0, 1]$ is open in this topology.

Comment: @RobertShore that just shows the set is closed (I did this), but we need it is the closure of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have more generally the following fact:

> If $A = B \times C \subseteq X \times Y$, then ${\rm Cl} A = {\rm Cl} B \times {\rm Cl} C$.

To show this, let $x \times y \in {\rm Cl} A$. Let $U$ be an arbitrary basis element of $X$ containing $x$. Since $U \times Y$ is a neighborhood of $x \times y$ in $X \times Y$, then it intersects $A = B \times C$; clearly, $U$ intersects $B$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, $x \in {\rm Cl} B$. The fact that $y \in {\rm Cl} C$ can be similarly shown by considering neighborhoods of the form $X \times V$, where $V$ is an arbitrary basis element of $Y$ containing $y$. Therefore, $x \times y \in {\rm Cl} B \times {\rm Cl} C$.

Now let $x \times y \in {\rm Cl} B \times {\rm Cl} C$. Let $U \times V$ be an arbitrary basis element of $X \times Y$ containing $x \times y$. Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, and $x \in {\rm Cl} B$, then $U$ intersects $B$; let $x'$ be an arbitrary point in this intersection. Similarly, since $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$, and $y \in {\rm Cl} C$, then $V$ intersects $C$; let $y'$ be an arbitrary point in that intersection. Note that $x' \times y' \in A \cap (U \times V)$. Since any neighborhood $D$ of $x \times y$ contains a basis element of the form $U \times V$ containing $x \times y$, then the above shows that $x \times y \in {\rm Cl} A$.

Applying this to your problem is easy. As you have already observed, the space you are concerned with is $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}_d$ refers to the real line in the discrete topology and $\mathbb{R}$ refers to the real line in its standard topology. The set $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}_d$ is already closed, indeed since *every* set is closed in the discrete topology; hence, ${\rm Cl} (0, 1) = (0, 1)$. The closure of $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $[0, 1]$, as one can check. From our lemma above, then ${\rm Cl} (0, 1) \times (0, 1) = (0, 1) \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer